# How to set raid on lvm in Debian?

Tags: linux, partitioning, debian, raid, lvm

I have 3 hard disks with lvm installed and I have 2 Logical Volumes created with lvm.
I want to make a raid with theese two logical volumes. Is it possible?
Like this scheme:

```
/etc /var /home
---------------
      raid
---------------
      lvm
---------------
 sda1 sda2 sda3
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that this is what you want to do?  RAID would normally be done *before* you apply LVM.  You want all of the LVM to be sitting on the array.  If you do the RAID now, it won't actually be RAID and will cause performance problems and not provide any protection.  RAID goes below LVM, not above it.

What you need to do is to back up your data, reinstall with MD RAID directly on top of your disks, and then add that as your PV and build the LVM layer there.